# How to set a calculator app button layout

Tags: android

I am trying to make a **calculator** app and I stuck on the layout. I want layout same as the stock layout but cant get the buttons to fill the entire screen. What layout would people suggest.

Comment: You need to read android documentation, get started on a tutorial or get a book and start trying to build the layout. This question you're asking is very unspecific. Please tell us what you tried and what didn't work.

Comment: i hope this will help u some how http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-a-calculator-app-for-android/28100

Comment: if it help u comment it or let me know what u want

Answer (score 2):

Use,

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum=".8"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
```

and distribute the weights evenly among all the buttons, like :

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            style = "@style/btnStyleHaiti"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:text=".Button Text." />

</LinearLayout>
```

This should evenly distribute the buttons.

Regards
Priyabrata

Comment: yeah got it using layout_weight, i just hadnt set it for all, i think, thanks

Comment: Alright, You are welcome :)